# DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE vs DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd") in Java 8+

Tags: java, date-formatting, java-time, iso8601, localdate

I have a date I’ve created using `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.of("+2:00")).minusDays(5)`. Now I want to format it as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

In Java 8+, is `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` the equivalent of `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")`?

The output appears identical and looks like, from the docs, they should be the same. However, the "LOCAL" part of that gave me pause. Notice I have an offset and I'm using ZonedDateTime. I wanted to make sure there were no any gotchas or "they're the same except under these special circumstances since you're dealing with offsets, etc".

Comment: can't you check [the sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.java#DateTimeFormatter.0ISO_LOCAL_DATE) or do some test?

Comment: First Google result: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE

Comment: I did read the docs and did testing both. The output appears identical and looks like, from the docs, they should be the same. However, the "LOCAL" part of that gave me pause. Notice I have an offset and I'm using ZonedDateTime. I guess I was more looking for any gotchas or "they're the same except under these special circumstances since you're dealing with offsets, etc"

Comment: "local" means "without time zone, without offset-from-UTC" when doing date-time work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For formatting a date-time denoting 5 days ago the two formatters will be equivalent. They will not be equivalent for all possible dates, neither for formatting nor for parsing.

Let’s try them out:

```
    DateTimeFormatter yyyyMmDd = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    int[] yearsToTest = { -900_000_000, -10_000, -2, 0, 1, 2017, 2099, 9999, 10_000, 900_000_000 };
    for (int year : yearsToTest) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, Month.DECEMBER, 2);
        String dateFormattedIso = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
        String dateFormattedYyyyMmDd = date.format(yyyyMmDd);
        String diff = dateFormattedIso.equals(dateFormattedYyyyMmDd) ? "Same" : "Different";
        System.out.format("%-18s%-18s%s%n", dateFormattedIso, dateFormattedYyyyMmDd, diff);
    }
```

The above snippet prints:

```
-900000000-12-02  +900000001-12-02  Different
-10000-12-02      +10001-12-02      Different
-0002-12-02       0003-12-02        Different
0000-12-02        0001-12-02        Different
0001-12-02        0001-12-02        Same
2017-12-02        2017-12-02        Same
2099-12-02        2099-12-02        Same
9999-12-02        9999-12-02        Same
+10000-12-02      +10000-12-02      Same
+900000000-12-02  +900000000-12-02  Same
```

So for formatting it seems they are equivalent for years in the common era (“AD”), but not for years before the common era. `yyyy` respects that there is no year 0, so a year of 0 in the `LocalDate` is rendered as year 1. It is understood that it is BCE, this information is not printed. The ISO formatter takes the year literally, with sign and all.

You may obtain the behaviour of `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` by using `uuuu` instead of `yyyy`.

“Local” here just means without time zone, in turn meaning that the time zone information from your `ZonedDateTime` isn’t printed, which you wouldn’t have expected anyway.

Comment: Another difference might be the lenient behaviour. As far as I know, the constant formatter is strict while the pattern-based formatter is smart in parsing. This is probably relevant for expressions like "2017-02-29" (rejected in strict mode and adjusted in smart mode).

Comment: Yes, @MenoHochschild, I didn’t consider differences in parsing, surely there are some. Thanks for your contribution in this direction.

Answer (score 2):

ISO here means [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  That format is currently, and probably will permanently be, yyyy-MM-dd (no timezone, since it's local).  But ask yourself this - do you want an ISO format, or do you want yyyy-MM-dd?  The fact that they're the same should be insignificant to you - you're making a decision based either on wanting a standard representation, or wanting a specific representation.  Or perhaps the question is "I'm not sure if I want an ISO format date...do I?" - to that the answer is, all things equal, you probably do.